# What is a heuristic fencepost?

Tags: gdb

And why does gdb seem to "hit" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_179.html), GDB is searching backward in the object code to find the beginning of a function, and it is hitting an imposed limit. If you can set the fence post limit to 0 or increase it, you might avoid the error, but it will take longer to run.